# A notation question: $|\langle x,y\rangle|$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Someone please explain what is the meaning of the words in shade

From [Proof from the Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK), 4th edition page 96:

> Let $q$ be a prime power, set $n=4q-2$, and let
>
> $$Q = \{x \in \{+1,-1\}^n: x_1 = 1, \#\{i:x_i=-1\} \text{ is even}\}.$$
>
> This $Q$ is a set of $2^{n-2}$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.
>
> We will see that $\langle x,y \rangle \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ holds for all vectors $x,y \in Q$.
>
> Remark: These 4 sentences came together.

And I need to understand what is $|\langle x,y \rangle|$ is in.

> We will call $x,y$ nearly orthogonal if $|\langle x,y \rangle|=2$.

Comment: "the book"? I guess there *is* only one...

Comment: Do you mean, **"Proofs from the Book"**, 4th Edition?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - Yes, and thank you again for your answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\langle x,y\rangle$ denotes the result of applying the inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the vectors $x$ and $y$ (which happen to be in $Q$); in this case, it is the usual "dot product". $|\langle x,y\rangle|$ denotes the *absolute value* of that operation.

E.g., $q=2$, $n=6$, $x=(1,-1,1,1,-1,1)$, $y = (1,1,-1,1,1,-1)$, then 
$$\langle x,y\rangle = (1)(1) + (-1)(1) + (1)(-1) + (1)(1) + (-1)(1) + (1)(-1) = -2$$
so $|\langle x,y\rangle| = |-2| = 2$.

Comment: What is $\#\{i:x_i=-1\} \text{ is even}\$ mean?

Comment: @Victor: If you have **multiple** questions about the notation, why not put them all in the question in the first place? It means "the cardinality" ($\#$) "of the set of indices corresponding to entries equal to $-1$". In other words, you are looking at vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, all of whose entries are either $1$ or $-1$, and such that the number of entries that are equal to $-1$ is even.

Comment: Appreciate to Arturo Magidin

Answer (score 0):

> $Q = \{x \in \{+1,-1\}^n: x_1 = 1, \#\{i:x_i=-1\} \text{ is even}\}.$

$Q$ is the set of all vector $x$ with *all* of the following conditions:

1. $x$ is a $n$-dimensional vector with entries $+1$ or $-1.$
2. The first entry in, $x_1 = 1.$
3. The number of indices $i$ where $x_i = -1$ is even. The cardinality of such set is even. i.e., the number of $-1$ component in the vector is even.

> This $Q$ is a set of $2^{n-2}$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.

$Q \subset \Bbb R^2,$ and the number of vectors in $Q$ is $2^{n-2}.$

> We will see that $\langle x,y \rangle \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ holds for all vectors $x,y \in Q$.

The [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition) between any two vectors in $Q$ is [congruent to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation) $2$ modulo 4.